# VBScript ASP Input-Type-Hidden, value with quotes

Tags: vbscript

```
<input type="text" class="originalValues" id="orig_<%=ColumnName%>" value="<%=FldValue%>">
```

Sorry, this would be the first time I couldn't find what I was looking for and actually had to ask a question.

I have a hidden input but if the value contains a quote ("), vbscript lops off the rest of the hidden inputs value.

How can I escape or replace the quotes?  These original values are compared to textareas to see if a change has been made and to add to the audit log.

Comment: <input type="text" class="originalValues" id="orig_<%=ColumnName%>" value="<%=FldValue%>">

Comment: sorry, the tags should look like the above

Comment: To format the code sample, you can highlight the code and click the "Code sample" button, which looks like `{ }` (or press ctrl+k on your keyboard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML, the proper way to escape the double quote is by using the `&quot;` character entity. If you always use double quotes to surround HTML attribute values, then you can use the built-in ASP method [`Server.HTMLEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to safely encode quotes and other characters that need to be converted.

```
Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(Chr(34) & "surrounded by quotes" & Chr(34))
```

output

```
&quot;surrounded by quotes&quot;
```

---

In reality, a safer method would be to also replace single quotes (apostrophes), since they could also be used to delimit attribute values. This could be done by writing a simple wrapper around `Server.HTMLEncode` and including it in your function library.

```
Function HTMLEncode(s)
    HTMLEncode = Replace(Server.HTMLEncode(s), "'", "&#39;")
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm getting closer.

Comment: so, like this in the html? value="<%=Response.Write(Server.HTMLEncode(Chr(34)&FldValue&Chr(34))%>

Comment: Or do I need to replace the string with &quot; ?